# Finding minimum and maximum value stored in a user input array in C

Tags: c, arrays, max, user-input, min

I'm trying to do two main things with this program:

- Getting the user to input numbers until they enter 0 or until they reach the end of the array.
- In the second part I want to find the minimum and maximum values stored in the array and print them.

The maximum value prints accurately, however the minimum value prints something which looks like an address.

This is my code so far, could you help me out?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int count = 0, store, array[SIZE], total;
    int min = array[0], max = array[0];

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter integer number %d. Press 0 to exit: \n", (count + 1));
        scanf("%d", &store);
        array[count ++] = store;
    } while ( count < SIZE && store != 0 );

    total = count;
    printf("Total number of values in array is %d.\n", total);

    for ( count = 0 ; count <= total && array[count] != 0 ; count ++)
    {
        if(array[count] < min)
        {
            min = array[count];
        }

        if(array[count] > max)
        {
            max = array[count];
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe min value is %d.\nThe max value is %d.\n", min, max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move `int min = array[0], max = array[0];` after you read the values.

Comment: You initialize your `min` and `max` wrongly since you don't even read in user inputs at that point so they could be some garbage values.

Comment: never declare/initialize multiple variables on the same line and you won't have these bugs.

Comment: @NadavS How is that??

Comment: You don't need two loops.  You can find the max and min as you receive the values.

Answer (score 0):

Move the min and max variables declaration for after the array is filled, like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int count = 0, store, array[SIZE], total;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter integer number %d. Press 0 to exit: \n", (count + 1));
        scanf("%d", &store);
        array[count ++] = store;
    } while ( count < SIZE && store != 0 );

    int min = array[0], max = array[0];

    total = count;
    printf("Total number of values in array is %d.\n", total);

    for ( count = 0 ; count <= total && array[count != 0] ; count ++)
    {
        if(array[count] < min)
        {
            min = array[count];
        }

        if(array[count] > max)
        {
            max = array[count];
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe min value is %d.\nThe max value is %d.\n", min, max);

    return 0;
}
```

then mininum value, however, will always be 0 if you write 0 to stop inserting numbers

Comment: There are two wrong things in your answer. First, you copied the same typing mistake the OP did in the condition of the for loop (`array[count != 0]` will always be element 0 or 1 of the array). Second, if the misstyped condition is made correct (and that is `array[count] != 0`) the value 0 will not be placed as a min because the for loop will exit.

Comment: @Tudor the code was tested and worked. I did not notice the array[count != 0] but it doesn't make a difference because the compiler will ignore it. I just focused on the problem and didn't read the whole code.

Comment: @DesislavaIvanova I'm glad I helped. Can you please set the answer as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This task can be done by a very optimized code, You code has many mistakes. But here I am just make correction in your code and providing comments with each correction, so it helps you to find the reason why it is not working and help you to understand program.

See the below code and must read all comments in code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int count = 0, store, array[SIZE], total;
    //int min = array[0], max = array[0];
    // above line will set garbase in min and max
     int min=0, max=0; // we will initialize it later
    do
    {
    printf("\nEnter integer number %d. Press 0 to exit: \n", (count + 1));
    scanf("%d", &store);
   if(store == 0){
       break;
     /* if you should not break here it put 0 in array so
       you always fiind 0 as min*/
    }
    array[count ++] = store;
    //above count ++ , its post increment so count is one more than total elements
    } while ( count < SIZE && store != 0 );

    total = count-1;
    /*count - 1 , reason , when you put last value in count,
    it incremented after that, because you are using post
    increment operator after that*/
    printf("Total number of values in array is %d.\n", total);
    if(total > 0)
    { /*it helps to initialize min with first element then
    it will update with your condition*/
      min = array[0];
      max = array[0];
    }
    for ( count = 0 ; count < total && array[count != 0] ; count ++)
    { // count < total, because loop starts from 0
    if(array[count] < min)
    {
        min = array[count];
    }

    if(array[count] > max)
    {
        max = array[count];
    }
    }

    printf("\nThe min value is %d.\nThe max value is %d.\n", min, max);
    return 0;
}
```

If there is any confusion then you should ask in comment, Good luck.
Code is checked on Turbo-C

Below one is code with some changes in your program, it helps you to understand the next level and you may think for a more better approach.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int count = 0, store, array[SIZE], total;
    int min, max; // we will initialize it later
    do
    {
    printf("\nEnter integer number %d. Press 0 to exit: \n", (count + 1));
    scanf("%d", &store);
    if(store == 0){
     break;
    }
    array[count++] = store;
    if(count == 1){
      min = array[0];
      max = array[0];
    }
    if(store < min)
    {
        min = store;
    }

    if(store > max)
    {
        max = store;
    }
    } while ( count < SIZE);
    if(count > 0){
     printf("\nThe min value is %d.\nThe max value is %d.\n", min, max);
    }
    else{
     printf("No element in array");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! These are great suggestions

Comment: Welcome, if it is working for you please mark answer as confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is (i think you misstyped it) the second condition in the for loop. If you test for `array [count != 0]`, the value of the expression `count != 0` can be either `1` or `0` so then you just access `array[0]` or `array[1]`.

If you want to correct it just replace it with `array[count] != 0` however this is not the good sollution. You already counted how many numbers you need to check, why not just ignore the last one (which is 0)?

Doing that, this is the code as you wanted it:

```
#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int count = 0, store, array[SIZE], total;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter integer number %d. Press 0 to exit: \n", (count + 1));
        scanf("%d", &store);
        array[count ++] = store;
    } while ( count < SIZE && store != 0 );

    int min = array[0], max = array[0];

    total = count;
    printf("Total number of values in array is %d.\n", total);

    for (count = 0; count < total-(total != SIZE); count ++)
    {
        if(array[count] < min)
            min = array[count];

        if(array[count] > max)
            max = array[count];
    }

    printf("\nThe min value is %d.\nThe max value is %d.\n", min, max);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that you old condition in the for loop `count <= total` produces undefined behaviour, since you access 1 element more to the right.

I also forgot to mention, but i guess you read it in the other answers... you have to move the line when you set the value to `min` and `max` to the first number in the array AFTER you read the array. Having `min = array[0]` before you had read any input will set a garbage value to `min` and then produce undefined behaviour.

---

Edit: if you are not sure if all input sequences terminate with a `0` you should change the for condition to also chech the last element which, in this case, is not a `0`. You can do this simply by replacing the for loop condition:

```
// until here the code is the same.

for (count = 0; count < total-(total != SIZE); count ++)

// and from here the code is the same.
```

With this your code should behave like this in the following situation:

- If `SIZE` is 10 and you input the numbers: `1, 2, 3, 4, 0`, the for loop will only check `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.
- If `SIZE` is 10 and you input the numbers: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, the for loop will check all the numbers because the expression `(total != SIZE)` will evaluate to `0` and thus `total-(total != SIZE)` is the same as `total-0`.

Answer (score 0):

there are mistakes in your code. First this initialization is miss placed `int min = array[0], max = array[0];` you can't assign value of `array[0]` to other variables when you don't have it. this initialization should come after `do-while`.(otherwise it's like using uninitialized variables)

second `array[count != 0]` this should be `array[count]!=0`.

also you should check this statement after scanning `array`  `if(count==1) return 0` this means user didn't enter any input.

also note here `count<=total` you are passing boundaries of your `array which will cause undefined behavior.

```
#define SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int count = 0, store, array[SIZE], total;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter integer number %d. Press 0 to exit: \n", (count + 1));
        scanf("%d", &store);
        array[count++] = store;
    } while (count < SIZE && store != 0);
    int min = array[0], max = array[0];
  if(count==1)
 {
  printf("no data");
  return 0;
 }
    total = count;
    printf("Total number of values in array is %d.\n", total);

    for (count = 0; count < total && array[count]!=0; count++)//or use count < total-1 instead of  total && array[count]!=0
    {
        if (array[count] < min)
        {
            min = array[count];
        }

        if (array[count] > max)
        {
            max = array[count];
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe min value is %d.\nThe max value is %d.\n", min, max);

    return 0;
}
```